# Writing a Scanner in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, lexical-analysis

I am trying to write a scanner that will read a C-file (.cm). When the scanner is complete, it will print each token along with the line number of the token. If the token is an identifier, the lexeme or string value of the identifier is printed; or if the token is a number, the value of the number is printed. Have I written this code close to achieving my scanner?? I'm having trouble with identifying if the input line is an identifier or int. I guess this is my attempt at a basic structure of the code.

```
  import java.io.File;<br>
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class ReadFile {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          try {
              Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
              System.out.print("FileName: ");
              File file = new File(input.next());

              input = new Scanner(file);

              count = 1;
              while (input.hasNext()) {
                   if (input.hasNextInt()){
                       input.nextInt()
                       System.out.println(count + ", " + input);
                       count ++}
                   else if (input.hasNext){
                       System.out.println(count + ", " + line);
                       String line = input.next();
                       count ++}
              }
              input.close();

         } catch (Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }       

  }
```

I have written something similar to this in Haskell, and I do prefer the functional language approach, but would like to give it a shot in Java.

Comment: Things like `if (String line == ID)` and `if (String line == int)` are not valid Java - this will not compile.

Comment: @Jesper, see it as a place holder for the code he's asking for.

Comment: you check the line in your if-else statement, but your line is not read...

Comment: It's a little more complex that what you seem to think. Integer and floating point literals, identifiers, string literals, character literals, symbols composed from special charaters, comments, line ends (quoted or not): quite a handfull. It'll take time...

Comment: you should try writing your code in Eclipse. it will help you to eliminate simple errors in your code... like `System.out.println(count + ", " + line);` before `String line = input.next();` which will obviously not compile

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you might like to think about.

For one, you're assuming that each token appears on a new line. That might be true for what you're doing; but it would be more flexible to use `input.next()` rather than `input.nextLine()`. That will read the next token, without caring whether it's on a new line or not.

To read in the next token and determine whether it's an integer or not, the easiest thing is to look at `input.hasNextInt()`. That will tell you, without advancing past the token, whether the next token can be parsed as an integer or not. If it is, you can read it with `input.nextInt()`; if not, read a `String` with `input.next()`.